# Efficient variable length bit array in c#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have a requirement to perform fast calculations on a bit array of a maximum of 140 bits. The operations I need are: bitwise comparison, bitwise operations (and, or, xor)

What is the most efficient way in terms of memory space to store this in C#?

Comment: Doesnt matter. Use byte[]. If you want that kind performance optimizations, use C++.

Comment: `BitArray` is, in my experience, slower than what you can easily make yourself. Also, if you want fast AND, OR and XOR and such, using bigger elements is better. That can also cause additional space to be wasted, though. So that's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

After some consideration, I will use an array of 18 bytes = 144 bits, having wasted 4 bits, and I will implement the padding in the byte array to simulate bitwise operations on the underlying 18 bytes.

Comment: So you will re-implement the `BitArray` class? http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html